# Multiple classes in one List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

So I am making RPG and I have multiple type Items(seperate classes) like:

```
Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
Armor armor = new Armor();
and etc.
```

Is it possible to make List that would be able to put all those same time like?:

```
List<Something> _currentItems = new List<Something>();
_currentItems.Add(new Weapon());
_currentItems.Add(new Armor());
```

Comment: Yes, If they all derive from `Something`

Comment: Create a Base class. Inherite all same time type classes from it. Then use downcasting to use them

Comment: Yeah Downcasting for the win, thanks all!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BaseClass
{

}
class Weapon:BaseClass
{

}

class Armor:BaseClass
{

}

List<BaseClass> currentItems = new List<BaseClass>();
currentItems.Add(new Weapon());
currentItems.Add(new Armor());
```